# Remove <a href > tag if it has specific format using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the an anchor tag in this format (username as link text) `<a href="#">@rey</a>`.

I want to remove a tag only if `<a>` tag contains the username format (@username).

Currently I have the following code for the task but it is not working as expected

```
let message= "Hello <a href="#">@rey</a> how are you doing ?"
const regex = /\B<a href='#'>@(\S+)<\/a>/g
const subst = `@$1`
message = message.replace(regex, subst)
console.log(message)
```

Comment: Hi ! Beware your pattern is looking for `'` char, not `"`. The `let` instruction must be invalid because of double `"` quotation.

Comment: @Philippe thanks for pointing out. The message is getting data from DB in real scenario.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've just added an answer.

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to do this for any security related purpose (e.g. removing links in a comment that you're going to post publicly on a page), you should know that you can't reliably remove/parse HTML with regex. C.f. https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tag could be anything, use this regex:

```
<(\w+)\b[^>]+>@(?<username>\w+)<\/\1>
```

if tag is fixed (i.e. `<a>`)

```
<a[^>]*>@(?<username>\w+)<\/a>
```

The replacment code:

```js
let message= 'Hello <a href="#">@rey</a> how are you doing ?'
const regex = /<(\w+)\b[^>]+>@(?<username>\w+)<\/\1>/g;
message = message.replace(regex, `$<username>`)
console.log(message)
```

> "Hello rey how are you doing ?"

Check the result [here](https://regex101.com/r/bqZde2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Quotation issue in the `let` instruction. The following should work :

```js
let message= "Hello <a href='#'>@rey</a> how are you doing ?"
const regex = /\B<a href='#'>@(\S+)<\/a>/g
const subst = `@$1`
message = message.replace(regex, subst)
console.log(message)
```

or even

```js
let message= 'Hello <a href="#">@rey</a> how are you doing ?'
const regex = /\B<a href="#">@(\S+)<\/a>/g
const subst = `@$1`
message = message.replace(regex, subst)
console.log(message)
```